# User generated images - where should these be stored (nodejs)

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project where users are able to upload images.

Project is built using MERN-stack.

I'm struggling to understand what is the best practice for storing user generated images? In a lot of the guidance, it seems that people store them in a public images folder within the backend nodejs server. I struggle to see how this scales, and if the application is a success it will need to store a high amount of images.

What is best practice for storing user generated images?

Best regards,
Oscar

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying your infrastructure in Cloud. The best way of storing the images is in the storage services like (AWS S3).

Currently, we are following the below pattern.

- If users signs in or sign up to our application, we keep the profile image in s3, s3 will generate the URL for every image.
- We will store the image URL in the database against the user.
- You don't need to worry about the scaling. S3 will automatically scale depends on the traffic.
- When it comes to availability, S3 is having 99.99999999999% availability.
- When it comes to cost, 0.023$ per GB, which is more suitable for our scenario.
- If you don't want to keep the images in public, S3 is providing a concept called pre-signed URLs.
- In pre-signed URL's S3 will keep the objects private, nobody can access the files. By generating the pre-signed URL only users can able to access the images or files

**Note:** I'm sharing this info as per AWS. Every cloud provider has its own static storage service which has higher availability and scalability.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Appreciated, I have been browsing the web for so many hours to understand this. I will try this approach!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best but below solution come to mine mind:

1. Implement APIs to put/get images
2. Storage images on your back-end server
3. You can control access by allow only user generated can get it by user id
4. Implement a schedule to clean up that files in that folder by a specific period, like 2,3 days ago.